# Missing node module error even though it's installed on a webdriverio/electron project. (ts-node)

Tags: electron, webdriver-io, ts-node

I cannot figure out why I am getting the below error. I'm trying to set up webdriver-io for an existing electron project.

```
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\automation\product\src\product.client\
node_modules\ts-node\esm\transpile-only' imported from C:\Users\user\automation\product\src\product.client\
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:437:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1009:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1218:11)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:580:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:294:18)
    at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:380:22)
    at initializeLoader (node:internal/process/esm_loader:74:49)
    at loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:87:11)
    at runMainESM (node:internal/modules/run_main:51:21) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I have been through the google desert. Of course I understand it's not found. But I can't figure out why it's not found? ts-node is installed. My package.json is below:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/chalk": "^2.2.0",
        "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.34",
        "@types/command-line-args": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/execa": "^2.0.0",
        "@types/node": "^14.6.0",
        "@types/request": "^2.48.7",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.18.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.18.0",
        "@wdio/cli": "^8.3.3",
        "@wdio/devtools-service": "^7.16.14",
        "chalk": "^4.1.0",
        "command-line-args": "^5.1.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
        "electron-chromedriver": "^13.0.0",
        "electron-packager": "^15.2.0",
        "electron-wix-msi": "^3.2.0",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
        "execa": "^4.0.3",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5",
        "wdio-electron-service": "^3.5.1",
        "webdriverio": "^7.7.4",
        "yarn-run-all": "^3.1.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "chart.js": "2.9.4",
        "electron": "^23.0.0",
        "react-number-format": "^4.8.0"
    }
}
```

Can any kind soul help me figure out what it's looking for or how to get around it? I'm very frustrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know if you already figured it out or not but I had the exact same error and it was a problem with the version of ts-node. So basically install a newer version of ts-node the one I installed was 10+. Hope this helps.

Comment: That did fix it. I updated from 8.X.X to a 10+ and it worked great. Thank you so much.